# Spring security configure access

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am configuring endpoint access in Spring Security. What I want to accomplish:

1. Everyone has access to resources
2. Everyone can login/register
3. Only authenticated users can access logout and all other mapped endpoints

Here is my configuration, it fulfills firs two requirements and prevents access to /logout for non-logged users.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("**/*.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("**/*.css").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("**/*.js").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                    
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutUrl("/logout");
```

Comment: As a side note, it's usual to use something like `/resources/**` or `/public/**` for static CSS/JS resources.

Answer (score 2):

to ensure that request to your application requires the user to be authenticated use 
**.anyRequest().authenticated()**